# A complete beginner - Can't isntall Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am a complete beginner. I am intetrested in data science, machine learning and artificial intelligence with Python.
I want to grow with this community and give back to you all as much as possible.

I am using python 3.9.

I downloaded and installed anaconda for python 3.8 (only version available on the website).

when i go to my command promt and type pip install jupyter (while being in the Anaconda scripts directory), i get a bunch of requirements already satisfied and

> WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL,
> however the ssl module in Python is not available. Could not fetch URL
> https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl
> certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max
> retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't
> connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) -
> skipping

how do i solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: SO, So i went to the directory where i downloaded python 3.9, went to the directory python 39/ scripts, and while that being the working file, I typed pip install jupter. 
It successfully installed!

However, when i type Jupyter Notebook

it returns
'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.